# How can I open link from webview in external browser in electron with sandbox?

Tags: electron

I have a `webview` with a page and Electron has `sandbox: true` in `webpreferences` object. And when I click on any link then nothing is happen. Yeah, I read how to fix it but every solution was in **NOT** sandbox mode so because I can’t use modules like shell or ipcRenderer in renderer thread. I want to open clicked link in external browser.

Comment: Is clicking on a link supposed to open it in a separate window, or should it navigate the current page. What's the expected behavior?

Comment: @pushkin want to open clicked link just in external browser. Now when I click nothing is happen. Here is resolve: https://gist.github.com/luizcarraro/2d04d83e66e3f03bef9b2e714ea8c0d7 but I can't have shell in renderer thread because I have a sandbox mode

Comment: Have you tried using a preload script in your webview to expose some Node APIs?